# Angular - Output & Event Emitter showing undefined in parent

Tags: angular, typescript, eventemitter

I want to allow users to upload a CSV file. I have my file input nested in the parent. I can console log the uploaded CSV file in the child component and see I have it fine but I receive undefined when I pass it through to the parent.

I guess I am not passing the correct value in the parent but I'm not sure what it should be.

child.component.html

```
<form class="mt-4" [formGroup]="csvForm" (ngSubmit)="uploadDocument()">
    <input type='file'
           name="fileUpload"
           id="txtFileUpload"
           #fileUpload
           (change)="changeListener($event)"
           accept=".csv"
           formControlName="csvFileUpload"
           required />
           
    <button (click)="uploadDocument(fileUpload.value)"
            type="submit">Upload
    </button>
</form>
```

child.component.ts

```
@Output() onSendCSV: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

changeListener($event: any): void {
    const files = $event.srcElement.files;
    this.ngxCsvParser.parse(files[0], { header: this.header, delimiter: ',' })
        .pipe().subscribe((result: Array<any>) => {
            console.log('Result', result);
            this.csvRecords = result;
        }, (error: NgxCSVParserError) => {
            this.csvForm.controls['csvFileUpload'].setErrors({ csvFileUpload: true });
            console.log('Error', error);
        });
    }

uploadDocument(csvRecords: any) {
    this.onSendCSV.emit(csvRecords);
}
```

parent.component.html

```
<csv-upload (onSendCSV)="collectCSV($event)"></csv-upload>
```

parent.component.ts

```
fileUpload: any[];

collectCSV(fileUpload: any) {
        console.log(fileUpload);
    }
```

Comment: Wild guess: can you check your imports? Are you sure you're importing the correct EventEmitter?

Comment: is this correct? - import { Component, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

Comment: yep it is the correct one

Comment: `this.onSendCSV.emit(this.csvRecords)` can you try this once?

Comment: @iamentafaz - this worked! Such a basic oversight. Thanks so much! Happy to mark as accepted answer if you post it

Comment: @Robgit28 Great! Do you want me to add the fix as answer?

Comment: @iamentafaz you should!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you've a property name `csvRecords` in your component class. So try emitting the `csvRecords` in your event emitter.

```
this.onSendCSV.emit(this.csvRecords)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok you are calling the same method twice in different ways:

1. ngSubmit `(ngSubmit)="uploadDocument()"`
2. button click `(click)="uploadDocument(fileUpload.value)"`

It appears that form submit (which has no input; hence `undefined`) is overwriting the button click.
Either change button `type="submit"` to `type="button"` from the button or provide the `fileUpload.value` in the form `ngSubmit` as well.

Best way: remove the click handler from the button and provide the input in `ngSubmit`. AFAIR `type="submit"` is good for accessibility

Comment: Appreciate the input on best practice on structuring, however @iamentafaz answer seems to have fixed the issue!

Comment: Ah I see you do have `csvRecords` as a field, yes that will solve it as well.

Comment: But note that if you go with that approach then `uploadDocument` method shouldn't take any parameter because `ngSubmit` is not providing anyinput

Answer (score 1):

Can you try emitting after the result is copied to csvRecords i.e.

```
console.log('Result', result);
 this.csvRecords = result;
 this.onSendCSV.emit(this.csvRecords);
```